# Add ImageView after text

Tags: android, text, textview, imageview

[image]

I want to achieve this functionality. Please provide a suggestion for it.

Comment: apply these styles in values-v19 folder if you want to apply for 4.4 kitkat... since u r applying these styles in values-v14 folder its is only effect the android 4.0 version ICS...

Comment: Since you are using appcompat, only apply style in values folder, delete other styles if you do not have specific styles for any other control

Comment: @Harry its working very fine without any extra style folder

Comment: @AnandSavjani where is your try ?

Comment: @robodev I have no try i want to achieve this functionality

Comment: @AnandSavjani try something from your side , we will help you.

Comment: I count five complete changes to this question - please note **this is seriously discouraged**. I have rolled back to your second question/version, to match the two answers below. Remember that if you modify a question after answers have come in, the answers are no longer relevant to future readers. Always, if you have a new question, ask a new one, rather than metamorphosing an old one.

Comment: @Anand, yes, please do not do that - it is regarded as vandalism here. If you are subject to a question ban then work with the system to get the ban lifted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this adds a drawable in a TextView after text.

```
TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.append("This is text with image!").append(" ");
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_new);
myIcon.setBounds(0, 0, test.getLineHeight(),test.getLineHeight());
builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(myIcon, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE),builder.length() - 1, builder.length(), 0);
text.setText(builder);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the Spannable interface, which can allow you to add images to a TextView.

If you want to know more about its usage, please read this [post](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/introduction-to-spans/). Its a really good read.